# Deleting the revision history of list of questions

Tags: support, revisions-list, revision-redaction

I need to delete all the revision history of the list of questions I have. I already have sent out an email to **team@stackoverflow.com** but so far I haven't got any email yet.

I have around 30-40 questions that were having some information so I edited those by  preserving the original intent of the question. So instead of flagging on those question, I have send out an email to above email id, explaining the situation and the list of questions as well in which revision history has to be deleted.

And I haven't got any response yet.

Do we know who will be in charge of deleting the revision history of the questions. I don't think so moderator is in charge of this. If I can figure out few names then I can talk to them directly about my problem.

Comment: For the record, I looked over every single post you had edited, and I saw precious little that could have at all been seen as "sensitive". There was one which had some names and such in it; that's the only one I can even imagine. What you seem to be sensitive about is the name of a company in some of the links - Public API links. I have no clue at all what is 'sensitive' about that.

Comment: I agree with you Andrew totally. Today I got a call from them regarding this and that is the reason I edited those questions right away so that they don't contact me again or take some action. So that is the reason I am little bit in hurry. I hope you will understand.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I can see though how a company might ask a user to disassociate themselves from the company name and account numbers.

Comment: @TechGeeky the fact remains that nobody on meta.SO can really make the company act any faster than the method you've already used.

Comment: So the method I have used is right. Then I am fine, I thought it might be I am missing something here.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Could be, definitely. (Which is of course not the same as me saying Stack Exchange should fully honor the request to remove edit histories; though it seems an account disassociation could be in order here)

Answer (score 4):

Moderators now have the ability to redact information from posts *when it's important enough*.  "Important" means things like passwords, authorization credentials, personally-identifying information of third parties, etc.  It does *not* mean "stuff I'm afraid my {boss, professor, spouse} will see".

The norm on Stack Exchange is that every action can be audited and, if necessary, reversed.  That's why high-rep users can see deleted posts and moderators can see deleted comments.  Redaction is not like that; it is a destructive operation, removing information from the database.  That's why redaction requires two moderators.  Redaction is also a complicated process, so moderators will decline requests that don't seem to be worth the hassle and damage caused.

I don't know what answer you got from Stack Exchange back in 2013 when you asked this, but if they redacted revisions of 30-40 questions for you, I hope you were profuse in your thanks and changed your future behavior to avoid getting into that situation.